# Is XSS in canonical link possible?

Tags: penetration-test, xss

During regular pentesting of my site I discovered that I can close double quotes in a canonical link tag and enter an ***onerror*** attribute with a simple javascript ***alert(1)***.

[image]

It is visible in source code but javascript did not execute.

[image]

I also tried with ***onload*** event but same result.

Is there a way an attacker can use different payload to execute javascript ?

Comment: How about a `>`?

Comment: @Bergi: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: You say that `"` is not properly escaped in the link tag attribute. Does it also accept `>` or `<` without transforming it to an entity reference?

Comment: @Bergi: No it does not. They are filtered out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [use the same trick](https://portswigger.net/blog/xss-in-hidden-input-fields) as can be used with `hidden` inputs:

> ```
> <link rel="canonical" accesskey="X" onclick="alert(1)" />
> ```

On Linux, use ALT+SHIFT+X to trigger the payload. IMHO it's enough to report the issue and get it fixed, but it does require some unlikely user interaction.

Other than that, I see no way to exploit this in a modern browser without further code.

While the `link` tag supports the `onload` attribute, it only fires when something is successfully loaded, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/test.css" onload="alert(1)">
```

If your injection were `<link href="[user input]" rel="canonical">`, then you could exploit it via `http://somedomain/somecsssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" onload="alert(1)`.

The WHATWG spec defines that the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43859478/1148035) attribute must be used, so it is unlikely that any browser would use the second, so this will not work for your case.

I tried all other event attributes, and none trigger on a normal page load.

This [blog post](http://www.websecuritylens.org/exploit-xss-in-are-filterred/) states that this would be exploitable under IE7 and IE8 by injecting a `style` attribute which then uses an expression to execute JavaScript.

If there is additional JavaScript code that insecurely processes elements, this might also become exploitable (see [here](https://hackerone.com/reports/227486) for an interesting example).

Comment: Thanks ! You saved my day. For Windows ALT + X works too. This could be chained with clickjacking (if present in website) to execute Javascript.

Comment: How to fix the issue then?

Comment: @NigelFds: By filtering out characters like **"**, **<** and **>**.

Comment: @NigelFds Most - but not all - of the time, you'd want to HTML-encode relevant characters (', ", <, >) when echoing user input. As this is in a URL context, you could also URL-encode the data (see [OWASP](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#rule-5---url-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-url-parameter-values) which also has a good overview of XSS prevention in other contexts, and when encoding of ', ", <, > is not enough).